# Google Maps Navigation ETA mismatch

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have to show the ETA between two GPS Location Lat/Lng in my application.

Here are my two sets of LAT/LNG

**Origin**
28.5198278,77.2007679

**Destination**
29.0000057,77.0406113

And to find out ETA I am using the [Following Google DISTANCE MATRIX API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=28.5198278,77.2007679&destinations=29.0000057,77.0406113&sensor=true):
**In the above case ETA is 1 hour 31 mins**

And to after that I have to show the Route between that Locations. For that I am using the following code:

```
String uri = https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=28.5198278,77.2007679&daddr=29.0000057,77.0406113
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
```

**Problem :** The main problem I am facing is that when I run the above URI in the browser, it gives me same ETA (**ETA is 1 hour 31 mins**
)as that it was found from above distance matrix API. **But when I use this Intent to open the Navigation Screen In Mobile APP, then in the mobile app the ETA time is different.**

(**In the mobile app case, ETA is 1 hour 57 mins**)

I am getting this difference for almost any sets of GPS Lat/Lng.

**I am unable to get why is this difference is coming in data in mobile and browser**

Looking forward for a valuable suggestion/guidance.

Thanks

Comment: I'm presuming there's multiple routes available and for some reason the app is selecting another (and not the quickest it seems) as it's default. As to why this is the case I'm unsure. I'll see if I can dig anything up.

Comment: Okay Thanks @Swires. Let me know if you found something else.

Comment: Nothings come up so far, it's an odd one, you're right the browser does display 1:31 but it also gives an alternate route of 1:57, so my first theory holds out.... Now just for the why!

Comment: Opening the link on my phone does display 1:56 (using the gmaps app), and the route that the desktop site shows is not displayed. I'd suggest raising the issue with Google. The fault is obviously not with you. Have you tried a different country (namely America as the routing is probably strongest)?

Comment: Yes the difference is coming, I have tested it with few example co-ordinates.

Comment: I think the GoogleMaps app takes traffic situation into account. Just a thought.